# How te measure performance a MVC website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, nhibernate

Our MVC website is very slow and I'd like to know how I can find the bottleneck. I use FireBug and I see that the request takes 15 seconds on the server. When I hit refresh, it takes about 3 seconds. I'd like to know how this is possible. What causes the 12 seconds?

Also, I think 3 seconds is also too long because the page I am requesting shows 25 records (from the database), a menu and some user info.

I've used the NHibernate profiler and I don't see any query that takes a long execution time. It's all a few ms.

Specs:

- The site is build with MVC 2
- We use Ninject
- We use NHibernate
- .NET 3.5
- We use a lot html.RenderPartial()
- SQL Server Express
- Log4Net

I hope that someone can help me to find the bottleneck(s). I don't know what I can try.

Comment: Use a .NET profiler, just as you did the DB profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio profiler :

http://www.slideshare.net/AbhijitJana1/tune-your-aspnet-application-using-visual-std
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mcs9VqreEps

Update (Reflecting on comment that OP have VS that doesn't have profiling feature) :

You can use EQATEC .NET profiler, it's free for personal use :

http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/

Comment: I use VS 2008 Professional, this version doesn't have the performance wizard ;(

Answer (score 2):

you can have look at [MVC mini Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/), that might be of your use.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the mvc-mini-profiler like Scott Hanselman explains here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx

Comment: Same time as Furqan! I like Scott's explaining :-)

Comment: I use visual studio 2008, that doesn't support nuget

Comment: Perhaps, since for all answers you need 2010, you could install the express edition. Copy the solution folder open it with 2010, convert and profile it. It won't be exactly the same as the original, but a 3-15 second long method probably would be detected. The 12 seconds could very well be caused by the webserver starting up your site by the way.